# Recently add new Drive, Which method below are best to boost Database performance

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, disk

I was using SQL Server, recently add Hard Disk, I want to use it to boost the Disk I/O for Database process if possible.

[image]

A. Merge Two Drive 
B. Split mdf(data) and ldf(log) across two drive.
C. Split mdf(data) into 2 ndf(secondary data) across two drive.

what method are the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with placing mdf and ldf into seperate drives and also this goes with the best practice of placing log files in its own drive..

I would also check if the disk is good enough for my needs,if not i will go with a good enough disk

There are some good articles which helps in how to configure hard disk and best practices..

http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.in/2009/03/sql-server-disk-configuration.html